# CFL integrated or non-integrated

Tags: light-fixture, recessed-lighting

My parent place come with non-integrated CFL fixture. Over the year, some of the socket, ballast and bulbs are out. I wondering if I should go to replace all of them to integrated CFL fixture. Is there any advantage non-integrated CFL over integrated CFL?

Comment: Replace it with the equivalent LED fixture.

Comment: LED cost far more therefore not considering LED at the moment

Answer (score 1):

CFL technology is entirely obsolete, so pouring additional money into that tech doesn't make much sense.

### Replace ballasts/lampholders if easy and cheap

The only reason to continue with non-integrated CFLs is if the ballasts and lampholders are readily available and cheap.

For instance, that is exactly what I do with 48" tube fluorescents, but ballasts and lampholders for those are dirt cheap.

### Switch to "integrated CFL" (???) fixture

An "integrated CFL" is the product most of us are familiar with, with a commonplace screw-in lamp base and the ballast on-board the "bulb".

The lamp base is usually the Edison E26 screw base, the one we're all very familiar with.  Sometimes it's the smaller candelabra screw-in base.

There are other goofy bases, such as GU24 - designed to stop you from using incandescent bulbs.  This meets some misguided energy-efficiency requirements, and means manufacturers don't have to certify fixtures for the high heat of incandescent bulbs.  Total waste of time: people just get adapters so they  can use the far cheaper Edison-base CFLs and LEDs.

So if you're changing fixtures, get a fixture with the common Edison E26 base. You can get  E26-base "integrated CFLs" *if you really want to*, but I recommend you take advantage of the very good pricing on "integrated LEDs", which are superior in every way including color temperature and light quality.

I just got rid of several dozen "integrated CFLs"; our household has gone LED.  I went with quality GE units on sale for $4 each.

### Modify your existing fixtures to Edison base, no ballast

It's the way to go if you're in love with the fixture and/or cost is a factor.  This will require some handyness. Sockets and lamp parts are readily available at respectable hardware stores, and to a lesser extent at big-box home improvement stores.

Again, this will allow you to use common off-the-shelf integrated "bulbs" of any technology you choose; limited to wattages below that of the old fluorescent bulb (since the fixture is not rated for any more heat than that.)